# Vim-jedi: change the location of the function signature window

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, jedi

I installed vim-jedi for autocompletion and I'm pretty happy about it except that when I open a parenthesis after a function name, the function signature appears at the top of the cursor and it is pretty annoying since the code "jumps" a few line.

Is it possible to change the location of this to be at the bottom of the cursor or in a split window at the bottom?

Thanks.
[image: 1]]

Comment: It seems that general popup appears at bottom if the current line is closer to top of the screen and popup appears at top of the line if current line is closer to bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

### Right from jedi `README`

Jedi displays function call signatures in insert mode in real-time, highlighting the current argument. The call signatures can be displayed as a pop-up in the buffer (set to 1, the default), which has the advantage of being easier to refer to, or in Vim's command line aligned with the function call (set to 2), which can improve the integrity of Vim's undo history.

#### Use this in your vimrc :

```
let g:jedi#show_call_signatures = "2"
```